# How to get last 12 months data and insert 0 if no data found for the month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get last 12 months data in Mysql using below query but i'm getting all the data not last 12 months data i gone through few of the post but helpful
My CreatedDate format is like '2020-04-17 12:03:59'

```
SELECT date_format(createdDate,'%m') as Month, 
       count(*) as count, 
       date_format(createdDate,'%Y') as Year 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL- 12 MONTH) 
GROUP BY Year,
         Month 
ORDER by Year desc,
         Month desc;
```

and also need help you Insert 0 if no data found in that month.

Comment: `DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL- 12 MONTH)` is ALWAYS true - so your WHERE do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a calendar table here:

```
SELECT
    cal.dt,
    COUNT(t.createdDate) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m') AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 9 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH), '%Y-%m') UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '%Y-%m')
) cal
LEFT JOIN tablename t
    ON cal.dt = DATE_FORMAT(createdDate, '%Y-%m')
WHERE
    t.createdDate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
GROUP BY
    cal.dt
ORDER BY
    cal.dt DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine for last 12 months but if i want to return 0 if no data available for that month how can i achieve.

Comment: This solution already does this, it reports the last 12 months.  Should a given month have no apperances in your table, it would report a count of zero for that month.

Comment: no i'm getting response like below                                                                                   2020-04 26
2020-01 1
2019-11 1

Comment: I'm getting the response as how many months data i have not all

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use a recursive CTE to generate the dates:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select curdate() - interval (1 - day(curdate())) day as yyyymm, 1 as lev
      union all
      select yyyymm - interval 1 month, lev + 1
      from dates
      where lev < 12
     )
select d.yyyymm, count(t.createdDate) as cnt
from dates d left join
     tablename t
     on t.createdDate >= d.yyyymm and
        t.createdDate < d.yyyymm + interval 1 month
group by d.yyyymm;
```

Note that this doesn't split the year and month into separate columns, but you can do that if you really want.

Also, this provide the current month with partial data.  You can adjust the logic if you only want complete months.